# Trying to start a private service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm trying to start a service. This service is not meant to be called by other application.

I am trying to call `startService` with an Intent that was created using Context and Class parameters. I'm trying to use `createPackageContext(getPackageName(), CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY)` to get the package context. `startService` however is having no effect, `onStartCommand` is never being called.

How do I start a service that is within the same package?

Comment: Put here the manifest and how you are calling the service, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I start a service that is within the same package?

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyServiceClass.class));
```